# How to run the C# SkeletalViewer sample provided in the Kinect SDK?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, kinect

Just downloaded the new Kinect SDK Beta from Microsoft and am really excited to start working. Only problem, I can't figure out how to run the provided SkeletalViewer sample program (the packaged executable runs fine but not the source code). Whenever I try to run it I get a FileNotFoundException for "INuiInstanceHelper.dll" at

```
nui = new Runtime(); //Line 78 in MainWindow.xaml.cs
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

**Update:**
Looks like it works now... I did not do much beyond updating Windows and maybe more importantly installing the DirectX Client (thought I already had it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.

The things you need to take into account for the camera are:

- Install the Kinect SDK from Microsoft.
- Connect the Kinect sensor to a full powered USB (preferably, one on the back).
- Reboot your system at least one time after everything was installed. *(My problem was originally fixed with this step)*

And for the speech recognition:

- If you are using a x64 bits version of Windows, when you install the speech prerequisites (they are listed on the readme), ensure to install the 32 bit version of the Speech library even when you OS is x64.

Comment: I think the Windows Update took care of the reboot for me. Thanks!